# ld: warning: ignoring file

Tags: ios, iphone

I am getting below warning

```
ld: warning: ignoring file [path]/libMAKit.a, missing required architecture i386 in file Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAViewController", referenced from: _OBJC_CLASS_$_AnalysisViewController in AnalysisViewController.o
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAChartView", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AnalysisViewController.o
   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MAKitTheme_WelterWeightDark", referenced from: objc-class-ref in AnalysisViewController.o
   "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_MAViewController", referenced from: _OBJC_METACLASS_$_AnalysisViewController in AnalysisViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like `libMAKit.a` not have simulator (i386) architecture, if you have source you can rebuild it but frequently third party libs ships without i386 architecture and can be usable only on real device

Comment: @sage is there any way to make it run on simulator.

Comment: @Arun yes there is a way, it's rebuilding from source for i386/x64 architecture

Comment: @sage444 can you please explain the steps to do it.I am Using imagPay framework,When importing this framework i am getting that error.

Comment: @Arun I'm not familiar with this framework, and steps can vary in depends of how framework is builds. I think you should ask additional question about this

Comment: @sage444 i will refer a link can you please guide me, there i have mentioned the error briefly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36978366/how-to-fix-missing-required-architecture-i386-in-file

Answer (score 1):

Try to find some missing files (red letters) like images. We spend most of one day just to figure it out that I didn't had all the images locally. (Sorry if it's bad english)