# How to fix missing required architecture i386 in file?

Tags: ios, ios7, ios5, ios4

I have developed a app in which I imported a iMagPay.framework,after compiling i got a error as shown below.

> ld: warning: ignoring file ./iMagPay.framework/iMagPay, missing
>   required architecture i386 in file ./iMagPay.framework/iMagPay (3
>   slices) Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_BluetoothHandler", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in BLEControllerViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EMVApp", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in EMVConstants.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EMVCapk", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in EMVConstants.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EMVHandler", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PaymentViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in TPaymentViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in ICCardController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EMVParam", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PaymentViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in ICCardController.o
>         objc-class-ref in BLEControllerViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_EMVRevoc", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in EMVConstants.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_M1Helper", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in M1CardControllerViewController.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Settings", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in PaymentViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in TPaymentViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in M1CardControllerViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in IndividualAppt.o
>         objc-class-ref in MagneticCardController.o
>         objc-class-ref in SetUpCardReader.o
>         objc-class-ref in SetUpCardReaderTab.o
>         ...
>        (maybe you meant: _OBJC_CLASS_$_SettingsPageViewController, _OBJC_CLASS_$_SettingsPageViewControllerTab )   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SwipeHandler", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in M1CardControllerViewController.o
>         objc-class-ref in IndividualAppt.o
>         objc-class-ref in MagneticCardController.o
>         objc-class-ref in SetUpCardReader.o
>         objc-class-ref in SetUpCardReaderTab.o
>         objc-class-ref in individualApptsTabs.o   "_OBJC_CLASS_$_audiotest", referenced from:
>         objc-class-ref in IndividualAppt.o
>         objc-class-ref in individualApptsTabs.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386 clang: error: linker command failed with exit
>   code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I am able to run the app in device, but not working in Simulator,I need to run the app in simulator can any one please help.

Comment: you missed the supporting files check once

Comment: @Anbu suporting files means? I cant get you.

Comment: is that third party files

Comment: i have imported those third party files. i am able to run i device. only in simulator i am getting those error.

Comment: Please reqirement all framework are add in your project

Comment: This happens when you add a framework to your project and unintentionally copy the framework into your project directory.

The fix is to check your project directory (where you store your project on disk) for any iphone SDK *.Framework files and delete them.

Comment: change your architecture of thirdparty and try , surely works

Comment: @anbu architecture in the sense armv7,armv7s?

Comment: dont take the risk bro run in device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you ask about this product [IMagPay Mobile Magstripe Credit Card reader](http://www.szzcs.com/english/productShow.asp?ID=61) 
and their SDK you obviously should contact support first

Also since this framework communicate with external hardware (card reader) creators not need to support simulators

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the framework is not built for the simulator. There can be two possibilities for this.

1. Some of the functions which this framework does might not be possible in the simulator (like payment processing).
2. The framework is not built universally.

If your case is first one then we can't do much with it.

If the issue is due to case second then please get a universal build for the framework and all things should work correctly then.

Comment: @Yohi I will try. my case is option one i think so.